# How to set the replication scope of an AD-Integrated DNS zone using WMI?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, dns, wmi

I need to use PowerShell to script the creation of some zones on Microsoft DNS Server (running on Windows Server 2008 R2); looks like there is no direct PowerShell support for managing the DNS server (yet), so WMI is the way to go.

I can create a new primary AD-integrated zone with this code:

```
$DnsZoneClass = ([WMIClass] "Root\MicrosoftDNS:MicrosoftDNS_Zone")
$DnsZoneClass.CreateZone("my.zone.name",0,$true)
```

The problem is, this automatically sets the replication scope of the new zone to "All domain controllers in this domain (for Windows 2000 compatibility)" and has no option for changing it.

How can I change this setting using WMI? I've been looking for a while at the documentation of the `MicrosoftDNS_Zone` class, but I wasn't able to find any way to do this.

Comment: See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779655(WS.10).aspx for the different scope options for AD-integrated zones. How to modify the default thru WMI methods, someone else will have to answer...

Comment: Yes, I know this is a directory partition issue; still wondering how to set it via WMI (or anything else), though...