# How to change the replication scope of an Active-Directory-integrated DNS zone?

Tags: .net, powershell, active-directory, dns, wmi

Related to this question: [How to set the replication scope of an AD-Integrated DNS zone using WMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571005/how-to-set-the-replication-scope-of-an-ad-integrated-dns-zone-using-wmi).

I need to change (using PowerShell, so .NET, ADSI or WMI) the replication scope of an Active-Directory-integrated DNS zone, i.e. the directory partition the zone it's stored in (DomainDnsZones or ForestDnsZone).

Can this be accomplished programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When either the GUI or DNSCMD is used to change the replication scope of a zone, I've observed the following process:

1) All of the DNS record objects are copied from the old location to the new location.

2) If (and only if) the copy completes successfully, the objects in the old location are deleted.  I observed one case where the process was interrupted, leaving a partial copy of the zone in the new location.  It caused some problems because the DNS service did not like seeing two versions of the same zone in different locations.

I'm not even sure it is that simple.  For instance, are changes tracked during the copy process?  My guess is no.  Consider replication partners who don't know about the change yet: They will still continue to update the zone in the old partition until the DNS service detects that the zone has moved.

So, if you can use ADSI to copy all of the DNS zone objects from the old partition to the new partition, then delete the objects from the old partition, that should do the trick.

Thus, while it is possible, it is not exactly simple.  Even with all the ADSI scripting I've done, I think I would still defer to DNSCMD or the GUI for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you can do this with WMI, but dnscmd can do it.  Note that if you're doing this remotely and your DNS server is running 2k8/2k8 R2 then you need to have a Vista or later version of dnscmd in order to support the improved RPC authentication.

[HOWTO for Server 2003](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784148%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_cmd)

[Server 2008 documentation of same command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772069%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_23)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I already knew about dnscmd (which also can create the zone in the right partition in the first place); but if possible I'd really prefer to avoid calling a command-line tool.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand the 'keep it native' instinct.  There are several things I've found that dnscmd will do that there doesn't appear to be documented exposure for.  Much of the DNS WMI classes are read-only, so except for querying I've found it mostly useless.

Comment: You can actually create zones, even DS-integrated ones; but the replication scope is set to Windows 2000 mode (i.e. in the System directory partition), and looks like there's no way to change it.

Comment: The WMI classes can create and update, but I've found them to continually be a dead end. Eventually, I find I just end up going back to DNSCMD. Now I just skip to DNSCMD most often. I have seen Bruce Payette (can't find link) argue that native commands are not poor practice, and doing extra work to avoid them is silly. External program usage is a *feature* not a *liability*.

Comment: Yeah, I know you can create and update things with the WMI classes, I just have found that they consistently lack the level of control I want, so I no longer bother with them except as a means to query the system.  If found it to be generally a waste of time to try to figure out how to do something with WMI when the documentation for dnscmd is so much better and the features so much more complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Zones = Get-WMIObject -Computer $ServerName -Namespace "root\MicrosoftDNS" -Class "MicrosoftDNS_Zone"
```

then use:

```
$Zones | Get-Member
```

and see if what you search for is there.

Comment: Tried, but there is nothing even remotely related to the replication scope and/or the directory partition.

Answer (score 0):

To modify scope zone to "All DNS servers in the forest" :

```
dnscmd /ZoneChangedirectorypartition $zone /forest
```

For domain:

replace `/forest` by `/domain`

and by /Legacy for : Windows 2000 capability